# Python CSV files

Tags: python

i am after a bit of help with looking at data in a csv file
the csv file is set out

```
week_no,w_day,t_time,set_point
1,Monday,4:45,17
1,Monday,5:15,15
1,Monday,8:00,17
```

the Python file is

```
import datetime
import os
import time
import csv
today_day = date.today().strftime("%A") # get todays day of the week
curent_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") # get hours and minuites
curent_week = 1 # set for csv read file
heating_set = 15 # set for set point

with open('c:\Heating_times.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
f.close()
```

which prints to the screen the contents of the file

What i want to do is  look data in columns and if all rows match then copy the value to heating_set

```
if curent_week = week_no and today_day = w_day and curent_time = t_time 
    heating_set = set_point from the csv file column
```

i have looked for examples of this but am unable to find any

Thanks for any help

Stuart

new code

```
import datetime
import os
import time
import csv
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

#today_day = date.today().strftime("%A") # get todays day of the week
#current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") # get hours and minuites
current_week = 1 # initial set for csv read file
heat_setting = 15 # initial set for csv read file

while True: # setup for heating on timers
    today_day = "Monday"
    current_time = "8:00"
#    today_day = date.today().strftime("%A") # get todays day of the week
#    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") # get hours and minuites

    with open('F:\Heating_times.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print (row)
            if row['week_no'] == current_week and row['w_day'] == today_day and row['t_time'] == current_time:
                heat_setting = row['set_point']
    f.close()
    print (current_week)
    print (today_day)
    print (current_time)
    print(heat_setting)
    time.sleep(10)
```

output window reads

```
OrderedDict([('week_no', '1'), ('w_day', 'Monday'), ('t_time', '8:00'), ('set_point', '17')])
1
Monday
8:00
15
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of simply reading the rows you should use the DictReader class from the csv module:

```
with open(...) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['week_no'] == current_week and row['w_day'] == today_day and row['t_time'] == current_time:
            heat_setting = row['set_point']
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for the reply i have entered the code above and corrected it for my spelling mistakes lol but it still is not reading in to the tag heat_setting not sure why ?

Comment: In order to get the heat_setting updated to what is in the file the code as written needs to match the day of the week (week_no (i.e., 1)), the week day (w_day (i.,e., Monday)) and the time (t_time) which is what the long if statement is checking.  If the current day and time does not match what is in the file the heat_setting will not be reassigned to match what is in the file.

Comment: i understand that that i had altered the csv file to the times when i was testing the program to week_no,w_day,t_time,set_point
1,Friday,03:20,18
1,Friday,03:21,19
1,Friday,02:22,17
1,Friday,03:23,18 and i print the heat_settingand current_time  to screen  to see what is going on

Comment: Try hard coding the today_day, current_time and current_week to match one of the entries and rerun the code.  I think that you will find that the heat_setting gets assigned.  For the above examples use: current_week, today_day, current_item = 1,Monday,8:00

Comment: OrderedDict([('week_no', '1'), ('w_day', 'Monday'), ('t_time', '8:00'), ('set_point', '17')])
1
Monday
8:00
15

Comment: Ok... So if you print out what is read in you will notice that the csv data is made up of strings and not integers.  Since row['week_no'] is a string and current_week is an integer the resulting comparison is False.  Thus the variable heat_setting is not assigned to the row value.  Changing row['week_no'] == current_week --> int(row['week_no']) == current_week should correct this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got it need to set the current_week and heat_setting as a string

```
import datetime
import os
import time
import csv
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

#today_day = date.today().strftime("%A") # get todays day of the week
#current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") # get hours and minuites
current_week = "1" # initial set for csv read file
heat_setting = "15" # initial set for csv read file

while True: # setup for heating on timers
    today_day = "Monday"
    current_time = "8:00"
#    today_day = date.today().strftime("%A") # get todays day of the week
#    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") # get hours and minuites

    with open('F:\Heating_times.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print (row)
            if row['week_no'] == current_week and row['w_day'] == today_day and row['t_time'] == current_time:
                heat_setting = row['set_point']
    f.close()
    Set_temp = int(heat_setting)
    print (current_week)
    print (today_day)
    print (current_time)
    print(Set_temp)
    time.sleep(10)
```

output window

```
OrderedDict([('week_no', '1'), ('w_day', 'Monday'), ('t_time', '8:00'), ('set_point', '17')])
1
Monday
8:00
17
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction